# Is it necessary to include width="auto" since this is the default?

Tags: html, css

I'm getting an error that says width="auto" isn't valid so I'm wondering if I just don't include it if it will default to width="auto"

I've tried removing it and it doesn't seem to affect the format of the email but I'm just curious if it's necessary at all.

```
<td width="auto" valign="middle" bgcolor="#0c50a3" align="center" height="40" style="font-size: 18px; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-weight: normal; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #0c50a3; border-radius: 4px; border-top: 0px None #000; border-right: 0px None #000; border-bottom: 0px None #000; border-left: 0px None #000; border-collapse: collapse;">
```

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Auto is the default value; it's only necessary to include it if you're overriding other CSS that would have set the element to a non-auto width.

Comment: Add your code please... `width="auto"` is not valid css. you mean `width: auto;`? hard to tell without your code

Comment: _"I'm getting an error"_ where are you seeing the error? The `width` attribute is a legacy attribute from before the days of CSS. You likely should not be using it.

Comment: The width CSS property sets an element's width.

Comment: Edited with the line of code

Answer (score 2):

Your premise is incorrect.

There are a number of elements in HTML which accept [a `width` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/fullindex.html#attributes-table). The acceptable values for them are:

> Valid non-negative integer

Some earlier versions of HTML allowed more elements to have a `width` attribute and sometimes to have a different kind of value (percentages were quite common).

`auto` is not a valid value for any `width` attribute.

It is a valid value for the CSS `width` property (although not always the default value) but CSS and HTML are different languages … even if sometimes they both include something with the same name.

So no, it isn't necessary or even (as the error message you mention says) allowed.